# If I connect a SATA3 6Gbps SSD to a SAS2 6Gbps port using a breakout cable, will I get SATA3 speeds?

Tags: performance, hard-drive, hardware, sas, sata

I have 2 SATA3 SSDs in my server, which are currently connected to SATA2 ports. If I wanted to get SATA3 speeds out of them instead, could I buy a SAS2 HBA and use an SFF-8087 to SATA breakout cable to get 6Gbps speeds out of it (since SAS2 is Gbps) or would I need a SAS3 or SATA3 card to get those speeds?

Comment: Depends on the card you buy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is true. The built-in controller will negotiate the speed according to either the slower component or maximum possible throughput.

Comment: Is this true of any SAS2 card? I've seen people online say that it depends on the card, but I have yet to find a single SAS2 card that doesn't explicitly call out support for SATA3.